# How to wait for IO operation when os.O_NONBLOCK mode is used

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, io

I use the [os.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open) with `os.O_NONBLOCK` mode to achieve non_blocking write/read in my code as:

```
os.open(path_to_file, os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY |os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

and

```
os.open(path_to_file, os.O_RDONLY)
```

Since `os.O_NONBLOCK` will return immediately, I want to ensure that reading/writing is done before reading or writing again to the same file later on in my code. I thought to use [os.wait()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.wait) but this works only with child processes, not with IO operations. Is there such a `wait()` function in Python that works with IO operation when `os.O_NONBLOCK` is used?

Note: I use nonblokcing operation to allow overlapping between some functionalities in my code. I use that in `C` code easily but I couldn't see such `wait()` when I work with Python

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for [`os.sync`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sync)? There's also [`os.fsync`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fsync) to force the writing of a single file descriptor.

Comment: @Blckknght I am not sure if this would allow the process to return while the writing is performed in the background somehow. I shall test. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the point of the `sync` functions. They block until the writes have been committed to disk (either all writes system-wide for `os.sync` or just writes to the specified file for `os.fsync`).